# Is it possible to get JavaScript code coverage from protractor and make it into Istanbul report

Tags: angularjs, protractor, code-coverage, e2e-testing, istanbul

Background:
I am working on a AngularJS Project that has 3 kinds of automated testing.
unit testing using jest,
end to end testing using protractor
end to end testing using robot framework

What we want now is to combine code coverage result from jest,protractor and robot framework. and merge it into a single Istanbul report

I would like to ask if 
1. Is it possible to get code coverage results from protractor?
2. Is it appropriate to the things I mention above? Are we supposed to put end to end test into code coverage?

Answer (score 1):

A1. Protractor is just an end to end test automation framework. It doesn't have inbuilt reporting mechanism to figure out test coverage.
 
A2. Mixing the unit test coverage with end to end test coverage isn't a good idea.

The coverage at Unit test level is to measure the test coverage around your functions or methods where as in end to end test you can simulate multiple user flows and it mostly covers happy paths, unlike unit tests where you can cover negative test cases as well.
I would definitely go with separate test coverage reports.